# what is relationship between agile and OOP?

Tags: asp.net, oop, agile

I am a .net developer.

Kindly guide what is relationship of agile and OOP ?

What I know is Agile is a process that recommend TDD and OOP is a way of writing code.

Are Agile and OOP both require to each other ? they are against each other or what please guide ?

Comment: They do not require each other and they both exist without the other.

Comment: Consider visiting http://programmers.stackexchange.com for conceptual questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOP is a programming language paradigm.

Agile is a software development process.

OOP languages are sometimes used where an agile process is used (i.e. in the same company  and/or project) - other than that, there is no relation.

Answer (score 2):

They are orthogonal. OOP is a programming paradigm as opposed to Procedural or Functional programming. Agile development has no implication on the programming paradigm used, but rather describes a mindset and a methodology how to approach software development in general.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, there is no relationship.  There may be an inferred association in the same way that people associate pancakes with breakfast.  Although pancakes and breakfast are often associated, there is no direct relationship which requires all breakfast eaters to consume pancakes.